# Show is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Message

Tags: vb.net

With the code below, I get the error:

> Show is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Message

```
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

        Dim iExit As DialogResult

        iExit = Message.Show("Confirm if you want exit", "Point of Sale" MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If iExit = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please explain what it is you're trying to do and how it's going wrong.

Comment: Please make sure you accept any answers that answer your question, and if they don't, explain why.

Also, as jwriteclub said, **please** actually explain the problem - just putting the error message in the title really isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is what I can get from your title:

> Show is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Message

Are you getting this error message? If so, here's why:

`System.Windows.Forms` has a class called `Message` as you ***may*** have noticed, but for what you are *trying* to use it for, that's not the correct usage.

I believe you want `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()` not `System.Windows.Forms.Message`

The `Message` class is used for something different.

---

I also noticed that you forgot a "," in between two of the arguments. So, the final code that I think you actually want is:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

    Dim iExit As DialogResult

    iExit = MessageBox.Show("Confirm if you want exit", "Point of Sale", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If iExit = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this is was you were looking for, and make sure in the future you don't just put the question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `MessageBox.Show` because `Message` does not contain `show` method.

```
 Dim iExit As DialogResult

    iExit = MessageBox.Show("Confirm if you want exit", "Point of Sale" MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If iExit = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
```

Comment: `Message` is actually a member of `System.Windows.Forms`, but it doesn't contain a static `Show()` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.message(v=vs.110).aspx